# Copy whole folder except one sub folder

Tags: except

I want to copy one folder which has many sub folders to another directory/drive.I just don't want to copy   one sub directory.This is what i am planning to do but with this i am getting an error except is not an internal or external command .

```
except "D:\Splunk\var" xcopy "D:\Splunk" "D:\test\Splunk_Withoutdata\%CurrentDate%\" /s
```

Thanks
VG

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it myself this is what i have done .I used Exclude command rather except .

```
xcopy "D:\Splunk" "D:\test\Splunk_Withoutdata\%CurrentDate%\" /EXCLUDE:D:\batch\list.txt /s
```

under `list.txt` I have mentioned the folder name which I want to exclude like `var\`.